# What is the meaning of paramattha dhamma?

Tags: vipassana

> '*Vipassana jahna is the focusing of the mind on paramattha dhammas*'.   (Sayadaw U Pandita, *In This Very Life*, p. 179)

What is the meaning of paramattha dhamma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Paramattha dhamma](http://www.dhammawiki.com/index.php?title=Paramattha)* is an Abhidhamma term, meaning the 'highest' dhamma.

The equivalent in the Pali suttas is called '*lokattura* (supramundane) dhamma' or 'heartwood'. Such dhamma is related to not-self ('*anatta*'), emptiness ('*sunnata*') & here-&-now liberation-&-Nibbana.

The [Ani Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn20/sn20.007.than.html) states:

> *Thus you should train yourselves: 'We will listen when discourses that are words of the Tathagata — deep, deep in their meaning,
>   transcendent (lokuttara), connected with emptiness — are being
>   recited'.*

*Paramattha dhamma* is the opposite of '*lokiya* (mundane) dhamma', which is about kamma, rebirth, metta & any other mundane moral dhamma which can be practised with 'self-view' by ordinary unenlightened people. The primary goal of lokiya dhamma is morality & non-harming. Where as the goal of paramattha dhamma is to extinguish all suffering. To quote:

> *Paramattha-dhamma (absolute truth of nature) is the Dhamma or the knowledge, which when we know it, will enable us to extinguish dukkha.
>   Ultimate truth then is the way the thing that helps us, enables us to
>   extinguish all dukkha.*
>
> [*Buddhadāsa Bhikkhu*](http://www.suanmokkh.org/system/books/files/000/000/048/original/Dependent_origination_suanmokkh_retreat_900810.pdf?1472200659)

The important distinction between 'lokuttara' ('paramattha') & 'lokiya' dhamma is found in the [Maha-Cattarisaka Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html), which explains two sorts of Right View:

> *And what is right view? Right view, I tell you, is of two sorts: (i) There is right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in
>   acquisitions [of becoming]; (ii) there is right view that is noble, without
>   effluents, transcendent (lokuttara), a factor of the path.*

For example, my posts on this forum are exclusively about '*paramattha dhamma*'.

Comment: Is it correct when I say that 'parramatta dhamma' is the absolute, ultimate, 'pure' reality of all phenomena, in casu: the phenomena as they really are (anicca, dukkha, anatta); the sense objects without the delusions of the mind?

Comment: Yes. Parramatta dhamma' is the absolute, ultimate, 'pure' reality of all phenomena, in casu: the phenomena as they really are (anicca, dukkha, anatta);